# Publish message to kapua using kura or MQTT

Tags: eclipse, raspberry-pi3, kura, kapua

I am working on an IoT device. I have installed Eclipse Kura in raspberry pi 3 
to use it as a gateway. I want to publish a message to Kapua server (installed in the same network) using Kura or directly using the raspberry pi. I have tried both methods.

**1- Using Kura**

I have followed the given instructions on GitHub Kura Kapua connection [tutorial](https://github.com/eclipse/kapua/pull/780/files) #780. After following these steps I am able to establish the Kura Kapua connection but unable to send data, Example.publisher package is also installed in Kura. I want to create a topic and publish data on that topic.

**2- Using MQTT-Client library**

I have installed the MQTT-Client library in raspberry pi and use the following commands to publish and subscribe the data.

To Publish :

```
sudo mosquitto_pub -h "broker-URL" -p "Port" -t "topic" -m "message" -u "user-name"-P "user-pass" -i "client-id"
```

To subscribe :

```
sudo mosquitto_pub -h "broker-URL" -p "Port" -t "topic" -u "user-name"-P "user-pass" -i "client-id"
```

this has the same behavior, It also establishes the connection but unable to create the topic and publish data.When I do the same for localhost it does send the message. I am using two different terminals to publish and subscribe.

Is there any method or example where I can actually send some data and observe at the other end using Kura or MQTT.

Answer (score 0):

## General knowledge

Correct connection parameters (if you followed the tutorial you mentioned) are:

```
-h localhost
-p 1883
-u kapua-broker
-P kapua-password
(not sure the doublequote is required)
```

Kapua uses has a specific topic format to grant access control over the topics.
The semantic of the format is:

```
{account-name}/{client-id/{semantic-topic}
```

Depending on your privileges you can access different levels of topics.

The defaults user `kapua-broker` allows only to connect, publish and subscribe under:

```
{kapua-sys}/{connection-client-id}/#
```

You need more permissions to subscribe to other `client-id` topics.
The permission required to do that is:

```
data:view
```

---

## Your example

First, it seems that you are using the published to subscribe. This is your command.

```
sudo mosquitto_pub -h "broker-URL" -p "Port" -t "topic" -u "user-name"-P "user-pass" -i "client-id"
```

Secondly credential, host, usenrname, password, and topic are all wrong (unless you "obscured" them before publishing to SO).

To make your test work you need to use the following commands,

**Subscribe**

```
mosquitto_sub -h "localhost" -p "1883" -t "kapua-sys/mosquitto_pub/my/test/topic" -u "kapua-sys" -P "kapua-password" -i "mosquitto_sub"
```

**Publish**

```
mosquitto_pub -h "localhost" -p "1883" -t "kapua-sys/mosquitto_pub/my/test/topic" -m "My test message" -u "kapua-broker" -P "kapua-password" -i "mosquitto_pub"
```

For the Kura example publisher, I don't know where could be the problem, due to lack of info. I'm assuming you are publishing or subscribing to a topic you cannot access to due to write/read permission on topics.

---

Hope that this help! :)